# Origine di 'processo alle intenzioni'

Tags: phrase-origin, proverbs

Stavo cercando di capire quale fosse l'origine di 'processo alle intenzioni' che spesso sento dire in frasi come:

> '*bla bla bla*, ma non vorrai mica fare il processo alle intenzioni?'

C'è qualcuno che ne sa qualcosa?

*bonus question*: E perché secondo molti sarebbe una cosa da non farsi?

Answer (score 4):

Il processo alle intenzioni è, come dice il nome, un giudizio su ciò che una persona ha (o aveva) intenzione di fare. Naturalmente, siccome nessuno a parte il diretto interessato può sapere esattamente quali siano questi pensieri, un processo alle intenzioni si basa necessariamente su supposizioni, che per loro natura possono essere false.

In uno stato di diritto, si viene giudicati e/o processati per ciò che si fa (ossia azioni concrete la cui portata puo essere percepita oggettivamente) e non per ciò che si pensa.
In altre parole, nessuno può processarti se pensi che bisognerebbe uccidere tutti gli X (dove X è una qualsiasi categoria di persone); però nel momento in cui torci anche un solo capello a un X, allora ti si può processare per la tua azione, perché siamo di fronte a qualcosa di concretamente valutabile.
Attenersi a fatti concreti è l'unico metro di giudizio possibile se si vogliono evitare situazioni ambigue (e anche così, succede ugualmente).

Questa la teoria; in pratica le cose non sono sempre (forse quasi mai) così chiare e nettamente definite.

Comment: Sì, anche perché di fonte agli omicidi la pena inflitta cambia soprattutto in base alle intenzioni del colpevole.